# MYSQL Query group by custom Month date?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I wrote a query that returns monthly sales.

```
SELECT
count(O.orderid) as Number_of_Orders,
concat (MonthName(FROM_UNIXTIME(O.`date`)),' - ',year(FROM_UNIXTIME(O.date))) as     Ordered_Month,
sum(O.total) as TotalAmount,
Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(O.`date`)) as Month_of_Year,
year(FROM_UNIXTIME(O.date)) as Sale_Year
FROM orders O
group by Month_of_Year, Sale_Year
order by Sale_Year DESC,Month_of_Year DESC
```

I would like to make it group for a custom date like

instead of 1st to 1st, it should group for 10th -10th of every month.
Not sure how to group it that way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are dealing with a time "shift", you'll have to do that math in your equation to "fake it out".  Something like

```
SELECT
      count(O.orderid) as Number_of_Orders,
      concat(
         MonthName( Date_Sub( FROM_UNIXTIME(O.`date`), INTERVAL 10 DAY )),
         ' - ',
         Year( Date_Sub( FROM_UNIXTIME(O.date), INTERVAL 10 DAY) )
            ) as Ordered_Month,
      sum(O.total) as TotalAmount,
      Month( Date_Sub( FROM_UNIXTIME(O.`date`), INTERVAL 10 DAY )) as Month_of_Year,
      Year( Date_Sub( FROM_UNIXTIME(O.date), INTERVAL 10 DAY )) as Sale_Year
   FROM 
      orders O
   group by 
      Month_of_Year, 
      Sale_Year
   order by 
      Sale_Year DESC,
      Month_of_Year DESC
```

So, in essence, you are taking the dates ex: March 11-31 + April 1-10 and subtracting "10 days" from them... so for the query, they will look like March 1-31, and April 11-30 will appear like April 1-20 + May, etc for rest of each year...

Answer (score 0):

Not tested.

```
group by Month_of_Year, ceil(day(o.`date`)/10), Sale_Year
```

This is a better idea in order to avoid having 4 groups but just 3

```
select 
month(my_date) as your_month,
year(my_date) as your_year,
case 
when day(my_date) <= 10 then 1
when day(my_date) between 11 and 20 then 2
else 3 end as decade,
count(*) as total
from table
group by 
your_month,your_year,decade
```

Adapt it to your needs.